# How do you create an excel document in WIX that can be shared and updated?

Tags: excel, logging, share

I creating my first web site using WIX and know little about programming. I would like to have an excel log that can be shared and updated by those who visit my web site. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try a google docs spreadsheet, those can be shared and updated. https://docs.google.com/#home